# MariaDB OPTIMIZE TABLE “grew” my table (as seen by the DB)

Tags: mariadb

DB is MariaDB 10.3 from the “official” Docker image storing the DB in a bind mount on ext4.

```
MariaDB [foo]> SELECT now(), TABLE_SCHEMA as DB, TABLE_NAME AS tbl, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024) AS Size FROM information_schema.TABLES where table_name = 'bar';
+---------------------+---------+-------------+--------+
| now()               | DB      | tbl         | Size   |
+---------------------+---------+-------------+--------+
| 2022-07-16 09:12:17 | foo     | bar         | 966544 |
+---------------------+---------+-------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [foo]> optimize table bar;                                                                                                               +---------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| foo.bar | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| foo.bar | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (1 min 45.992 sec)

MariaDB [foo]> SELECT now(), TABLE_SCHEMA as DB, TABLE_NAME AS tbl, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024) AS Size FROM information_schema.TABLES where table_name = 'bar';
+---------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| now()               | DB      | tbl         | Size    |
+---------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| 2022-07-16 09:15:29 | foo     | bar         | 2684384 |
+---------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [foo]>
```

The file size of the table also grew(!) if only moderately:

```
# du -sk foo.*
      4  foo.frm
2707456  foo.ibd
# du -sk foo.*
      4  foo.frm
2723840  foo.ibd
#
```

I had hoped to reduce the file to the table size and not increase the DB table size to the file size, obviously.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Can you never reduce the file size by `OPTIMIZE`? I knew that InnoDB Tablespace never got shrunk on Disk, but I thought that was different with recreate, which I expected to happen and according to output really did happen here. Do I actually have to create a table with a different name from it to effectively “pack” it?
2. Could it be that the previously apparently too small table size in the DB was just wrong and indicates a deeper underlying problem with the DB?

---

Definition as requested:

```
CREATE TABLE `bar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `searchKey1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tsAsRfc3339` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `searchKey3` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `searchKey2` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `sk1Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `anotherId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_sk3` (`searchKey3`),
  KEY `idx_sk2` (`searchKey2`),
  KEY `idx_sk1` (`searchKey1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19965936 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Don’t have a definition from before. Didn’t know the Definition could change from an `OPTIMIZE TABLE`?

```
MariaDB [foo]> select count(1) from bar;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
| 19941649 |
+----------+
1 row in set (17.696 sec)

MariaDB [foo]>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for not wasting time with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  You seem to have found a new reason.

`OPTIMIZE` *usually* shrinks the table size, but not enough to be worthwhile.

Apparently you did have `innodb_file_per_table = ON`?  With "off", the activity would have been inside the file `ibdata1`, which does not get rebuilt, nor shrink.

That table started out as nearly 1GB?  There is no "too small".  A small percentage increase happens sometimes, but your 2.7x increase is puzzling.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If possible, show that also for before the Optimize.  Maybe something changed by default.

Comment: Yeah, file per table, the ibdata1 for the installation is relatively small at only 11G. This was a trial run for compacting much much bigger tables and – oh boy! I put the definition in the question. At this point I’m pretty sure the original size in the mysql CLI was just wrong, but why, how, and is it a problem?

Comment: @BerndHaug - I would not expect Optimize to change the table structure.  But the Engine and/or indexes might have been changed by a version upgrade.  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'bar';`  It smells like half the disk space is taken up by the secondary indexes.

Comment: Hmm good guess, ~55% according to that. Seems weird to me since the text columns are hardly ever empty and those are just trees over a few numbers, with a not very wide histogram on two of them. And no, we haven’t done a version upgrade at all yet, though we need soon according to https://endoflife.date/mariadb.